# des command on openssl 3.0 unsupported crypto error

Tags: openssl

I am using openssl version 3.0.0.7 and running following DES command for encryption. Running this command on windows10 command prompt. input file `secret_messge.txt` consists of following

```
hi there, the message is secret, hi there
```

and command used is below

```
openssl enc -des-ecb -e  -in secret_message.txt -out simple-cipher-message.bin -K b2a2d62eab19114f
Error setting cipher DES-ECB
6C0C0000:error:0308010C:digital envelope routines:inner_evp_generic_fetch:unsupported:crypto\evp\evp_fetch.c:346:Global default library context, Algorithm (DES-ECB : 4), Properties ()
```

Answer (score 5):

DES encryption is considered legacy and is no longer available by default in the "enc" command. To use it you would need to load the legacy provider, e.g.

```
openssl enc -des-ecb -e  -in secret_message.txt -out simple-cipher-message.bin -K b2a2d62eab19114f -provider legacy -provider default
```

Comment: thanks for response. While running above command I am facing below error: enc: unable to load provider legacy
Hint: use -provider-path option or OPENSSL_MODULES environment variable.
EC090000:error:12800067:DSO support routines:win32_load:could not load the shared library:crypto\dso\dso_win32.c:108:filename(C:\Program Files\OpenSSL\lib\ossl-modules\legacy.dll)
EC090000:error:12800067:DSO support routines:DSO_load:could not load the shared library:crypto\dso\dso_lib.c:162:
EC090000:error:078C0105:common libcrypt.
Not sure how to fix this.  Can you help me out what I am missing. thanks

Comment: This error says that OpenSSL is trying to load the legacy provider but can't find it in the location that it expects to, i.e. (C:\Program Files\OpenSSL\lib\ossl-modules\legacy.dll). So, the first thing to check is does that file exist and is it readable? If it doesn't exist then see if you can find it somewhere else on your system. Did you build OpenSSL yourself - or did you download it as a pre-built binary? Its possible that whoever built the binaries either didn't build the legacy provider, or its been installed to some unexpected location

Comment: Thanks @Matt Caswell for your valuable inputs. I have downloaded pre-built binary, i think this binary does not consists legacy binaries.

Comment: If you don't have the legacy.dll file anywhere on your system then you will not be able to use legacy algorithms with the "enc" command (like DES). I'd suggest finding a pre-built binary from somewhere else that does have this file if this is important to you. The project doesn't distribute binaries itself, but it does maintain a list of 3rd party built binaries here: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries

Comment: Pass the argument "-provider-path=<PATH_TO_OPENSSL_BIN_FOLDER>", now it's working fine, I think that the path is hardcoded...bad design

Comment: The default PATH to the provider module directory is determined at compile time and can be changed at runtime by setting the `OPENSSL_MODULES` environment variable.